# Netlify react router redirect configuration breaks css links

Tags: css, react-router, web-crawler, seo, netlify

Google crawl-bot is triyng to access `https://my-website.com/.../index.231e3e.css`

But, because my app is a react-router app, I have this redirect rule configured:

```
[[redirects]]
from = "/*"
to = "/"
status = 200
force = false
```

which redirects the css path to the main home page (loading the website, rather than a css file).

I'm not sure how the CSS gets loaded in the background when you do visit the normal website - because the styles load in fine - but when I directly access this css link, it redirects to the home page.

I'm wondering how I can fix this redirect issue allowing google indexer to properly style my page (currently the page looks broken in the rendered screenshots, due to the missing css files which failed to download).

---

It seems now the css loads (maybe 1 time error) but the web page is still rendered incorrectly with no css

[image]

Comment: I will be surprised if the CSS loads when you load your website normally, but the same URL fails when you directly visit the link. Could you share the URL?

Comment: That's probably because React has not added the styles in the JavaScript parsed version by Googlebot? Could you try to use Prerendering if it helps? Note that, Netlify's default prerendering output remains cached for about 48 to 72 hours, so if you make any changes, it might not be immediately reflected on Google.

Comment: @HrishikeshKokate Still happening

Comment: Can't comment anything further without seeing the site.